# Cannot create object from simple class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net core mvc application in which I need to take a object and serialize it to json, so that I can  pass it as a payload to a API.

I have almost the same code working in a similar setting.

So I have the action `Updateuser()` that just creates a object of type `hashcontainer` and tries to serializwe it to json string:

```
public class hashContainer
{
    public string h;

    public hashContainer(string s)
    {
        this.h = s;
    }

}
 public  IActionResult Updateuser()
 {
     ApplicationUser u = new ApplicationUser();

     var hass = new hashContainer("pikkemand");

     string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hass);
```

But when I add a breakpoint at the last line here, the object "hass" is null.
This is super weird. I have also tried not using a constructor, putting the model in my model folder et cetera. Whatever I do, I cannot create this object, what is wrong?

It's har to add more detail to this questions, as it is a extremely simple problem, and I have no clue what could be the cause.

The code can be found [here](https://github.com/S3j5b0/IDX2021_1/blob/main/mongoExample/mongoExample/Controllers/APIController.cs) line 88

Comment: What does *I cannot create this object* mean?

Comment: it is null when I create it

Comment: Don't use "var", use hashContainer. Why do you use "var" ?

Comment: @Leandro *Why do you use "var" ?* - why do you advocate *not* using it?

Comment: With the greatest respect, `hass` *cannot* be null straight after it's been instantiated. It's just not possible. Maybe you're debugging a dll that is different to your source code?  In some way you have misidentified the issue though - what you describe isn't possible.

Comment: @NotQUiteSo1337 you're asserting that as soon as `var hass = new hashContainer("pikkemand");` has run, it is null? Show me how you're determining this; screenshot please. Put the cursor on that line, press F9 so it goes red, run the code until it stops with a yellow bar, press F10 one time, then take a screenshot of whatever thing says it's null

Comment: Welcome to C#.... omg

Comment: Im aware that it's strange, adding getters and setters seems to have changed something

Comment: After this statement: `var hass = new hashContainer("pikkemand");` has run (i.e. if you have a breakpoint on the next line), then `hass` will necessarily be non-null.  The exception would be if you are debugging a release build.  In that case, the code would likely be generated as `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new hashContainer("pikkemand"));`.  Are you debugging a debug build??

Comment: Source on given link suspictious. You are calling ````new hash()```` on line 87, but class ````hash```` has no parameterless constructor at all. Assuming this constructor available and the execution goes further on line 88 you are writing ````hass.h = "yoyoyoyo";````. If you position the cursor on ````.h```` part it will show you ````null```` because this member of ````hash```` was never initialized to other than its default value. Move the cursor to ````hass```` it should not be null as others already explained.

Comment: So, the source you show in your question is not the source in your program.  Bye.